# Create a larger string from an array of strings

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, string, split

I have an array of strings which looks like this

```
var input = new [] { "AB-PQ", "PQ-EF", "EF=CD", "CD-IJ", "IJ=XY", "XY-JK" };
```

I want to have a string output which should be like this

```
var output = "AB-PQ-EF=CD-IJ=XY-JK"
```

I want to know if there is a better way to do this instead of using a brute force for loop and then splitting and combining using string builder.

My Business Use-Case :
My business use case is such that the given string represents a sequence of links between two cities in a route containing multiple cities. A '-' means road link and '=' means rail link. City code can be of any length.

Comment: will there be `-` or `=` only? or can have more different characters?

Comment: There can be any delimiter but right now it is just these 2.

Comment: The main problem here is that you have described the end result, which means you will get answers that focus on getting that specific end result, and not how to get there.

Comment: What about `new[] { "AB-BC", "CD-DE", "BC-CD" }`? (notice the order)

Comment: And how long are the substrings? Are they really all exactly 2 characters?

Comment: You need to describe the rules you're following to go from the first to the second, otherwise every time you come up with more information it will be "Yeah, but ..." for every answer here and that will just waste everybodies time.

Comment: I suppose in that case should be "AB-BC-CD-DE"

Comment: I think it's questionable as to whether any of the answers are actually better than your 'brute force loop'. Linq is still iterating over every item in the array, but the logic can be a lot clearer in a loop. It's great to reduce it to a single line of code, but it is not very readable when it needs 6 or 7 steps.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen The sequence will always be like what I have mentioned. i.e. AB-BC, BC=XYZ, XYZ=SDE etc. The substrings can vary in length. It is not necessarily 2 length.

Comment: @pango89 - Will they always pair like this? The previous suffix matches the current prefix?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, It will always pair like this. My business use case is such that the given string represents a sequence of links between two cities in a route containing multiple cities. A '-' means road link and  '=' means rail link. City code can be of any length.

Comment: @pango89 - And that should also be in your question.

Comment: @Enigmativity I am sorry about that. I will update my question. Thanks for guiding a beginner :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I am using and it seems to be working. It is much easy to understand.

```
public static string Get(string[] array)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (var i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        var link = array[i];
        var words = link.Split('-', '=');
        sb.Append(words.First());

        // Link will contain either of the separators
        if (link.Contains('-'))
        {
            sb.Append('-');
        }

        if (link.Contains('='))
        {
            sb.Append('=');
        }
    }

    sb.Append(array.Last());
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
var input = new [] { "AB-PQ", "PQ-EF", "EF=CD", "CD-IJ", "IJ=XY", "XY-JK" };

var output = String.Join("",
    input.Take(1).Concat(new [] { String.Join("", input.Skip(1).Select(x => x.Substring(2))) }));
```

I don't like it, but it works. It produces `"AB-PQ-EF=CD-IJ=XY-JK"`.

---

Try this as a more robust alternative:

```
void Main()
{
    var input = new[] { "AB-PQ", "PQ-XYZ", "XYZ=CD", "CD-A", "A=XY", "XY-JK" };

    var output =
        input
            .Select(i => new Segment(i))
            .Aggregate(
                "",
                (a, x) => a + x.ToString().Substring(a == "" ? 0 : x.Origin.Length));
}

public enum Mode
{
    Road, Rail
}

public sealed class Segment : IEquatable<Segment>
{
    private readonly string _origin;
    private readonly Mode _mode;
    private readonly string _destination;

    public string Origin { get { return _origin; } }
    public Mode Mode { get { return _mode; } }
    public string Destination { get { return _destination; } }

    public Segment(string descriptor)
    {
        var parts = descriptor.Split('-', '=');
        if (parts.Length != 2)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Segment descriptor must contain '=' or '-'.");
        }
        _origin = parts[0];
        _mode = descriptor.Contains("=") ? Mode.Rail : Mode.Road;
        _destination = parts[1];
    }

    public Segment(string origin, Mode mode, string destination)
    {
        _origin = origin;
        _mode = mode;
        _destination = destination;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Segment)
            return Equals((Segment)obj);
        return false;
    }

    public bool Equals(Segment obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(_origin, obj._origin)) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<Mode>.Default.Equals(_mode, obj._mode)) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(_destination, obj._destination)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 0;
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(_origin);
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<Mode>.Default.GetHashCode(_mode);
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(_destination);
        return hash;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{_origin}{(_mode == Mode.Rail ? "=" : "-")}{_destination}";
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Segment left, Segment right)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(left, null))
        {
            return object.ReferenceEquals(right, null);
        }

        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Segment left, Segment right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }
}
```

Comment: It need not be a 2 letter thing as written here. It can be of any length. e.g. AB, XYZ, A,  123 etc

Comment: @pango89 - Then that should be in your question. Please update it. Please also provide real data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) and `string.Join` like this:

```
var input = new[]{"AB-PQ", "PQ-EF", "EF=CD", "CD-IJ", "IJ=XY", "XY-JK"};
var result = input[0] + string.Join("", input.Skip(1)
                          .Select(c => string.Join("", c.Skip(2))));
```

Just don't forget to add this to your `using` directives first:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version:

```
var input = new [] {"AB-PQ", "PQ-EF", "EF=CD", "CD-IJ", "IJ=XY", "XY-JK"};
var output = string.Join("=", string.Join("-", input).Split('=').Select(x => string.Join("-", x.Split('-').Distinct())))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = new [] { "AB-PQ", "PQ-EF", "EF=CD", "CD-IJ", "IJ=XY", "XY-JK" };

var r = input.Aggregate((total, current) => 
            total + current.Substring(OverlappingCharCount(total, current))
        );
```

You can define `OverlappingCharCount` method to always return 2 (as in your example, the strings always overlap by exactly 2 characters), or use some smarter logic to handle more generic cases.

Answer (score 0):

Achieve the same using Regex:

```
string str = string.Join("-", input);
Regex oRegex = new Regex(@"\b(?<Captured>\w+)-\1\b",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
oRegex.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().ToList().ForEach(items=>str = str.Replace(items.ToString(), items.Groups["Captured"].ToString()));
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete answer

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = new string[] { "AB-PQ", "PQ-EF", "EF=CD", "CD-IJ", "IJ=XY", "XY-JK" };
            var output = input[0] + string.Join("", input.Skip(1).Select(c => string.Join("", c.Skip(2))));
            Console.WriteLine(output);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```